# Angular JS ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Tags: angularjs, authentication

This is the code:

**loginCtrl.js**

```
var loginapp = angular.module('loginapp', []);  
loginapp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$http','loginService' function($scope,$http,loginService){
 $scope.doLogin = function() {loginService.login($scope); }; //call login service
 }]);
```

**loginService.js**

```
'use strict';
var loginapp = angular.module('loginapp', []);  
 loginapp.factory('loginService',function($http){
return{
    login:function(scope){
        var $promise=$http.post("login/do_login", {'username': $scope.username, 'pass': $scope.pass});
                     //send data to user.php
                console.log($promise);
        }

       }
});
```

**Browser says at console:>** loginCtrl.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function  (error on line 2)

**Whats wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your controller definition:

```
var loginapp = angular.module('loginapp', []);  
loginapp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$http','loginService', function($scope,$http,loginService){
   $scope.doLogin = function() {loginService.login($scope); }; //call login service
}]);
```

Comment: Comma given/added.
Now Error: 
Browser says at console:> Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: Try changing `loginService.js` to this: `var loginapp = angular.module('loginapp');` If that doesn't work then post more detail on your error output.

Comment: If I change as you said: Browser says: Error: $injector:nomod.

Angularjs . org says: Module 'loginapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Your module is not being declared. You only need this line to appear once across your js files: `angular.module('loginapp', [])` That declares your module. Now to associate controllers, factories, etc. with that module you do: `angular.module('loginapp').controller(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
loginService.login($scope)
```

this is bad aproach!

make user object and pass it, not the whole world

and if that promise, get result in .then()

```
$scope.user = {'username': your_user_name, 'pass': your_password};
$scope.doLogin = loginService.login($scope.user).then(function(result){
   ... get result
});

.....
login:function(user){
    var $promise=$http.post("login/do_login", {'username': user.username, 'pass': user.pass});
     //send data to user.php
     return $promise;
    }
   }
```

Comment: I have done with this. But the Error not ger solved.What to do? I am new to This.

Comment: Browser says at console:> Error: [$injector:unpr]

Answer (score 0):

You have missing comma here:

'loginService' function